Access Accessibility service api in android through react native
I am currently working on a app in which I need to create a feature that can open a different app and read it's screen and extract the data from that app screen.
Codebase is in react native of my app and i can't find any way to access accessibility Service api in ReactNative.
I tried AccessibilityInfo api in react Native but it was no such help for my use case.
